# Word2Vec similarity function not working

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm using PyCharm and loading models trained on words using Word2Vec. I tried to check the similarity between two words, but I get this error :

```
# Loading model trained on words
    model = word2vec.Word2Vec.load('models/text8.model')

    # Loading model enhanced with phrases (2-grams)
    model_phrase = word2vec.Word2Vec.load('models/text8.phrase.model')

    # Words that are similar are close in the sense of the cosine similarity.
    sim = model.similarity('woman', 'man')
    print 'Printing word similarity between "woman" and "man" : {0}'.format(sim)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 974, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
File "C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/code/word2vec/embedding_word2vec_students.py", line 144, in <module>
sim = model.similarity('woman', 'man')
File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 1194, in similarity
return self.wv.similarity(w1, w2)
File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 587, in similarity
return dot(matutils.unitvec(self[w1]), matutils.unitvec(self[w2]))
File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 567, in __getitem__
return self.word_vec(words)
File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 271, in word_vec
return self.syn0[self.vocab[word].index]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I debug, it seems that the problem comes from this line in the function word_vec :

```
return self.syn0[self.vocab[word].index]
```

However I have no clue why I'm getting this. Thank you very much in advance if you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like 'woman' or 'man' might not be a part of your vocabulary. First thing I would check is whether they occur in the model you are loading.